# calcular factorial en python usando el bucle for xd

Tags: python, bucle-for

Tengo el siguiente programa en python alguien que sepa la solución o sepa lo que esta mal
porque me pide que ingrese dos veces el número y no se porque y tmb el bucle esta mal.

```
def pedirDatos():
    print("Ingrese su edad");                                                                                                    
    edad=int(input());
    return edad
    
datos=pedirDatos()

def calculaFac(datos):
    lista=[]
    i=datos;
    for acum in range(1,datos):
        i=i-i;
        acum=datos*i;
        print(acum+"\n");


def principal():
    pedirDatos();
    calculaFac(datos);


principal();
```

Answer (score 1):

Respetando tu código, esta podría ser una solución a tu problema:

```
def pedirDatos():
    print("Ingrese su edad");                                                                                                   
    edad=int(input())
    return edad
    
def calculaFac(datos):
    factorial = 1
    for i in range(1,datos+1): 
        factorial = factorial * i
        print(factorial)
    return factorial


def principal():
    datos=pedirDatos()
    print("El factorial del número {} es: {}".format(datos, calculaFac(datos)))


principal()
```

Ejemplos:

Para `edad=23`:

```
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
39916800
479001600
6227020800
87178291200
1307674368000
20922789888000
355687428096000
6402373705728000
121645100408832000
2432902008176640000
51090942171709440000
1124000727777607680000
25852016738884976640000
El factorial del número 23 es: 25852016738884976640000
```

Para `edad=14`:

```
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
39916800
479001600
6227020800
87178291200
El factorial del número 14 es: 87178291200
```

En tu código se pide dos veces la edad, porque haces dos llamadas al método que te pide entrar los datos, en: `datos=pedirDatos()` y `pedirDatos();` (este último en el método `principal`).

Comment: Gracias me ayudó mucho